# openweathermap weather.icon is showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what my webpage looks like: http://prntscr.com/dg6dmm and my codepen link: `http://codepen.io/johnthorlby/pen/dOmaEr`

I'm wanting to get the weather.icon from the api call and use that icon identifier (in this example "02n") and show an icon from https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions depending on what the weather is, but this is just showing as undefined but if you look on the screenshot in the whole call the icon is "02n".

Here is my html:

```
<div class="main" id="temp">
    <h1>Weather!</h1>
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <img src="">
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  background-color: #BEBDCE;
}
.main{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #8E9EBC;
  padding: 10px;
}
.main h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var api = "43881a1bf31fb1b7225348b3f7839a9d";
  var city = "Oslo";
  var wData;
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=" + api, function(json) {
    wData = JSON.stringify(json);
    var name = JSON.stringify(json.name + ", " + json.sys.country);
    var temp = JSON.stringify(json.main.temp);
    var icon = JSON.stringify(json.weather.icon);
    temp = Math.round(temp);
    //update h2 with city, country and temperature and testing to see what weather.icon is but comes back as undefined
    $("#temp h2").text("The temperature in " + name + " is " + temp + "°C " + icon);
    //testing to see if there is a icon in the api call which there is "02n"
    $("#temp p").text(wData);
    //display image of weather type from https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
    $("#temp img").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weather is an array in the JSON, you need to pull the data out of it correctly.  Also, your output String has " " around it so we need to remove those.

```
var icon = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].icon);
icon = icon.replace("\"","");
icon = icon.replace("\"","");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!